# Recon-ng v5 - How to add domains?

Tags: exploit, tools, updates, reconnaissance

I just started with recon-ng today, I was following tutorials but every tutorial is outdated with most of them describing the functions of v4.

I was able to update myself with simple additions like the marketplace and the new way to add modules etc. But, for example, if I'm using netblocks module "whois_orgs", how do I add a domain?

The command used to be "add domains" if I'm not mistaken, I tried "create domains" no luck (assumed it was create because they replaced add with create for workspaces), but now either command outputs "Invalid command", when I type in "show", it lists "domains", so I'm pretty sure there should be a way to access it.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer, it's:

> db insert domains

same thing with others as well, for companies it's "db insert companies"